# memory upgrade is causing dual monitor problems

Tags: upgrade, ram

I added memory (4GB to a 4GB system), and now I have problems using 2 monitors.  Ubuntu works fine with one monitor (built in laptop), but when I plug in the external monitor, the built in monitor becomes scrambled.  Is there anything that I need to change in the system (20.04) after the upgrade?

Comment: Have you confirmed the RAM module is properly seated into the motherboard? It may also be worthwhile to conduct a memory test to make sure that the modules are healthy.

Comment: I discovered that the new memory was a lower voltage then the original memory, which caused it to randomly freeze.  I verified the problem with the GRUB memory test on start up.  Apparently, only some systems you can mix and newer (lower voltage 1.35) with older systems (1.50), and others it does not work.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. Hopefully you can arrange an exchange for a more compatible memory module 